Global Commands Dialogflow CX
Does anyone know if it is possible to incorporate a " global type" command in Dialoge-flow CX" without programming the intended functionality throughout the entire flow. For example, if someone wants to transfer to a representative at any point during the phone call/flow by saying "transfer" or pressing "0". I am not a programmer. My programmer is telling me that it is a very tedious task involving programming the functionality throughout the flow versus a global "anytime" command to process the transfer. I hope my question makes sense. Any help is greatly appreciated.

In dialogflow CX exists a thing called Event Handler, that if this eventHandler is set in the Start Page, the event handler affect all the flow (not only for the start page).

Open the flow start page.
Click the add add button in the Event handlers heading.
The event handler panel opens.
Provide event handler fields.
Click Save.

For example, you could create a handler for a predefined event "no-input", "no-match", "webhook failed" etc, but you could create a handler for a custom event, for example, a intent with numeric entity type.
